# Spring won't load controller classes for JavaFx views

Tags: java, spring, javafx, spring-boot

I'am currently working on a project in which I'm using Spring and JavaFX and I ran into a problem.
I have initially a login frame and after the user presses Login button another frame has to appear. The problem is that after I build my second FXML file (for the second frame) and try to link it to its controller the Spring won't make this linking for some reason. I have annotated my controller class with @Component but it does make any difference. If I do not set my fx:controller (leave it empty) , the frame successfully loads. I've been spending the last 6-7 hours on this issue and I haven't found any satisfactory answer.

My **Controller** class looks like:

```
package project.eHealth;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import project.eHealth.bussiness.AppointmentDto;
import project.eHealth.bussiness.AppointmentService;

@Component
public class DoctorViewController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<AppointmentDto> appointmentTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<AppointmentDto,String> doctorNameColumn ;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<AppointmentDto,String> patientNameColumn ;


    @Autowired
    private AppointmentService appointments;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        patientNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getPatientName());
    }

    @FXML
    public TableView<AppointmentDto> getAppointmentTable() {
        return appointmentTable;
    }


    public void setAppointmentTable(TableView<AppointmentDto> appointmentTable) {
        this.appointmentTable = appointmentTable;
    }


    @FXML
    public TableColumn<AppointmentDto, String> getDoctorNameColumn() {
        return doctorNameColumn;
    }


    public void setDoctorNameColumn(TableColumn<AppointmentDto, String> doctorNameColumn) {
        this.doctorNameColumn = doctorNameColumn;
    }

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<AppointmentDto, String> getPatientNameColumn() {
        return patientNameColumn;
    }


    public void setPatientNameColumn(TableColumn<AppointmentDto, String> patientNameColumn) {
        this.patientNameColumn = patientNameColumn;
    }


    @FXML
    public AppointmentService getAppointments() {
        return appointments;
    }


    public void setAppointments(AppointmentService appointments) {
        this.appointments = appointments;
    }

}
```

It's corresponding FXML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="project.eHealth.DoctorViewController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.4882943143812709" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="appointmentTable" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="289.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="doctorNameColumn" prefWidth="95.0" text="Patient Name" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="patientNameColumn" prefWidth="105.0" text="Date Issued" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="23.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Patient name" />
                  <Label layoutX="30.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Date Issued" />
                  <Button layoutX="172.0" layoutY="227.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" text="Accept" />
                  <Button layoutX="172.0" layoutY="277.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" text="Reject" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The main application class :

```
package project.eHealth;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



@SpringBootApplication
public class EHealthApplication extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    private Parent rootNode;
    private Stage primary;
    private Stage doctorStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        context = SpringApplication.run(EHealthApplication.class);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primary = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
        primaryStage.setTitle("E-Health Login");
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        context.close();
}

    @FXML
    void showDoctorFrame() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Handle regular User");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(EHealthApplication.class.getResource("DoctorView.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        rootNode = loader.load();

        doctorStage = new Stage();
        doctorStage.setTitle("PatientView");
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode);
        doctorStage.setScene(scene);
        doctorStage.show();
    }

}
```

The method that is executed after the login button is pressed is *showDoctorFrame()*

The stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Dragos/Desktop/eHealth/target/classes/project/eHealth/DoctorView.fxml:8

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at project.eHealth.EHealthApplication.showDoctorFrame(EHealthApplication.java:60)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:929)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 61 more
```

Any kind of help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `EHealthApplication` both as the `Application` class *and* as the controller for one of the FXML files?

Comment: @James_D yes, I do

Comment: That's your problem then: `init()` is not invoked on the controller instance, so `context` is null in the controller. You should not use the `Application` class as a controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the same class as the `Application` class and as the controller class for your main fxml file. This is generally a bad idea.

`Application.launch()` (approximately) creates an instance of the `Application` class, starts the FX toolkit, calls `init()` on the instance created, creates a primary stage, and then calls `start()` on the instance created on the FX application thread. Note that in your case Spring is not managing this instance: it is created externally to the spring bean factory.

If you specify this class as the controller for the FXML file, then the FXML loader will "create" an instance of the controller class when the FXML file is loaded. Note that in this case, since you specify a controller factory for the FXML loader, it will create this instance by invoking the controller factory, so it gets the "controller instance" of the class from the spring bean factory. However, this will be a different instance of `EHealthApplication` than the one which was created by `Application.launch()`.

The `context` field in `EHealthApplication` is initialized in the `init()` method. This method is invoked on the instance created by `Application.launch()`. So `context` is never initialized in the "controller instance" which was obtained from the spring bean factory (as `init()` was not invoked on that instance). Consequently, when the event handler method `showDoctorFrame()` is invoked, `context` is null and you get the null pointer exception when the FXML Loader tries to process the `fx:controller` attribute in the doctor view FXML.

You should use a separate class for the main controller. Since the `ApplicationContext` is a "well known Spring object", you can inject it directly into the (Spring-managed) controller:

```
package project.eHealth;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



@SpringBootApplication
public class EHealthApplication extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    private Parent rootNode;
    private Stage primary;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        context = SpringApplication.run(EHealthApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // UI work should really be here, as it's on the FX Application Thread
        // (though I think you can get away with it in the init() method)
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
        this.primary = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
        primaryStage.setTitle("E-Health Login");
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        context.close();
    }



}
```

and then

```
pacakge project.eHealth ;

// imports omitted...

@Component
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context ;

    private Stage doctorStage;

    @FXML
    void showDoctorFrame() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Handle regular User");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(EHealthApplication.class.getResource("DoctorView.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        Parent rootNode = loader.load();

        doctorStage = new Stage();
        doctorStage.setTitle("PatientView");
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode);
        doctorStage.setScene(scene);
        doctorStage.show();
    }

}
```

and change the `fx:controller` attribute in the main fxml file to point to this new class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're a true lifesaver!!